# How to change Angular themes default text color?

Tags: html, css, angular, themes, textcolor

I am using Angular 8 and `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`
 theme, and want to change the default gray color of texts but I am confused about it and seems it's so hard! I searched and tried some suggestions in other questions but couldn't understand them!

Please help me know if there is a simple way to change the color of texts in an Angular application?

Comment: Does overwriting the styles of the [typography classes](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
Look up here you may find your answers. My suggestion would be, Create your own theme instead of changing the default theme and import in style.scss or style.css or may be other

Comment: I read the page but couldn't understand what is the answer of my question?